# Spyder executing in terminal although I selected iPython

Tags: terminal, ipython, spyder

I'm on a Macbook. I have been using Spyder for a while with no trouble, but this morning when trying to run my scripts, it was not executing within the iPython screen, but rather in a separate terminal. Or rather it appears to start executing in the iPython screen but then the rest of it runs in a terminal window. I have no idea why this happened but I would very much like for all of my codes to run within the Spyder iPython window, not in the terminal.

[what shows up in the iPython console when I hit run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFfMw.png)
[run executes in the terminal window. I want all this to happen in the iPython window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiIeb.png)

Any help?

Thanks,
Ty

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The code you're running probably needs to do it in a terminal, and that's the reason you're seeing it after evaluating your code.

Comment: Hi Carlos, the code has worked all this time with no problems within Spyder. It was only a few days ago it started running in the terminal window.

Comment: Then I don't know why this happens, sorry.